# Displaying a different variable in VIEW sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view

creating view:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewHolidayID AS
    Select Package_Code, Description, Country_Visted
    FROM tbl_Holiday_Details
```

Select query :

```
Select * from viewHolidayID
WHERE Country_Visted
```

In Country_Visted Column shows a list of countries. what i am trying to do, rather than showing the countries individually, shows the continent.
For example, 'China' will show 'Asia', 'India' will show 'Asia', 'Italy' will show 'Europe'. I dont want it to permanently change the variable, just to show when using the select query

Comment: We have no idea what you have done -- you have to show us the source of what you have done.

Comment: post the code you have

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: There i altered the question i hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

This could be an "easy" way:

```
select Package_Code,
       Description,
       Country_Visted,
       case (Country_Visted)
         when 'Italy' then 'Europe'
         when 'India' then 'Asia'
         when 'China' then 'Asia'
       end as continent_visited
from tbl_Holiday_Details
```

However, this is a really poor approach, given that every time you add a new country you have to edit your code to handle the new value.

A better solution could be defining a new table to store the continent of every country and join it to your table:

```
create table CountryContinent(country, continent) as
(
select 'Italy', 'Europe' from dual union all
select 'India', 'Asia' from dual union all
select 'China', 'Asia' from dual
)       

select Package_Code,
       Description,
       Country_Visted,
       c.continent
from tbl_Holiday_Details h
     inner join CountryContinent c
     on (h.Country_Visted = c.country)
```

In this way you only have to add a row in your table when a new country appears in your table, without modifying the code